# Passing array to AXIOS post

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios

I have this array:

```
postData = [region_id: 18, net_forces: 29, region_adder: 1, my_game_action: "deploy", active_player_id: 1]
```

And I want to post it using `axios` and I cannot seem to achieve this.  I am looking to end up with:

```
axios.post(turn_route, {
  region_id: 18,
  net_forces: 29,
  region_adder: 1,
  my_game_action: 'deploy',
  active_player_id: 1
})
```

I have tried:

```
axios.post(turn_route, JSON.stringify(postData))
.then(function(response) {

axios.post(turn_route, postData)
.then(function(response) {

axios.post(turn_route, data: {postData: postData})
.then(function(response) {

axios.post(turn_route, {params: {postData}})
.then(function(response) {
```

I cannot find an example of what should be common. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

postData is not array, it's object and correct definitions is 
    `postData = {region_id: 18, net_forces: 29, region_adder: 1, my_game_action: "deploy", active_player_id: 1}`

You need
   `axios.post(turn_route, postData).then(function(response) {})`

Comment: Hi @Ruslan Popov I tried it again, but still in my headers I see `[]` Request Payload. Yet the `console.log` just before the Axios call shows the object I posted.